# Creating multiple subsets all in one data.frame (possibly with ddply)

Tags: r

I have a large data.frame, and I'd like to be able to reduce it by using a quantile subset by one of the variables. For example:

```
x <- c(1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10)
df <- data.frame(x,rnorm(100))

df2 <- subset(df, df$x == 1)
df3 <- subset(df2, df2[2] > quantile(df2$rnorm.100.,0.8))
```

What I would like to end up with is a data.frame that contains all quantiles for x=1,2,3...10.

Is there a way to do this with ddply?

Comment: Save your keystrokes: `x <- rep(1:10, 10)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
ddply(df, .(x), subset, rnorm.100. > quantile(rnorm.100., 0.8))
```

And off topic: you could use `df <- data.frame(x,y=rnorm(100))` to name a column on-the-fly.

Comment: Thanks Marek, for the answer and the tip about specifying a colname on the fly - although not requested, it was something I was wondering how to do!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach with the little used ave() command. (very fast to calculate this way)

Make a new column that contains the quantile calculation across each level of x

```
df$quantByX <-  ave(df$rnorm.100., df$x, FUN = function (x) quantile(x,0.8))
```

Select the items of the new column and the x column.

```
df2 <- unique(df[,c(1,3)])
```

The result is one data frame with the unique items in the x column and the calculated quantile for each level of x.

Comment: `ave` is one of most powerful R functions. But in this case I think you should use it in this way: `subset(df, rnorm.100. > ave(rnorm.100., x, FUN=function(v) quantile(v, 0.8)))`

Comment: that clarifies the question for me... :)

Comment: I've not had the opportunity to try this function before. Marek's solution above works well for my purposes. But thank you for this as well, I'll look into "ave".